# Parse string received from nodes server in React Native

Tags: node.js

A string is returned from nodejs server:

```
return res.status(200).send(longString);
```

Then parse in React Native app:

```
let res = fetch(url);  //fetch the long string from server
let longstring = await res.text(); //<<==causes an error below

[Error: You attempted to set the key `_V` with the value `1` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.]
```

Why `res.text()` didn't work here? If the long string was sent back in an object, then `res.json()` works fine and returns original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the `Content-Type` of the response and the type of data you are returning.

I'm guessing `application/json` is being picked.

Try setting the content type on your server by doing:
`res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");`

Comment: It is nodejs/express with `app.use(express.json());` for the project. If `text/html` is added, how this text content type is going to work together with the `application/json`?

Comment: According to the docs, `Returns middleware that only parses JSON and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.`. So you can add as many middleware as you want and they will handle matched request